# How to render the movie texture in the Open GL viewport rendering?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

I try to render animation using ***Open GL render animation*** option. I added a movie clip as a texture to a plane. 
[image]

When I change the keyframes manually (in ***Material*** viewport shading ) the following animation frames are visible (they're refreshing right).
[image]

Interesting fact is, it only works this way if the *Preview* panel is expanded. 
[image]

The problem appears when I try to render it using ***Open GL render***. Despite the fact that I enabled the '***auto refresh***' option in Image Texture node the animation on the plane is not visible (it display only the current frame image). Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: check to see if its working with the normal render , if it is then something with GL is wrong / different.

Comment: I had problems with this before, preview from movie image nodes glitched in viewport and only worked well in render. For me the texture updated when the cursor was in the correct window when playing animation with alt-a, sometimes I had to select the object itself or it was just random..

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Jerryno's tips, I've found an answer how to do this finally in ***Cycles***. I've discovered, that to make it work, Blender has to have the preview of the texture visible. So I've set up windows as below. In one window you have the *viewport shading* set to ***Material*** and in other one it is set to ***Rendered***. 
[image]

When you press *play* button all images refresh fine. After pressing the ***Open GL render active viewport*** button (or clicking Render--> Open GL Render Animation) you get the movie with an animated texture. Don't know why, but sometimes you'll have to press/click it few times until it works though.
...............................................................................................................................................

I tried to make it work in ***Blender Internal*** also. When you press *play* button images don't refresh, unless you do one tricky thing. You have to keep the *Preview* and *Image* panels of the ***Texture header*** expanded. Then you hover the cursor over *Preview* panel and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Now the images in the ***Texture*** *viewport shading* are refreshing well. Sadly they don't behave the same after pressing the ***Open GL render active viewport*** button. I guess making the *Open GL animation render* with a working video texture is impossible in BI.
[image]