# Materials Drivers not updating on viewport?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, drivers

I want to do 2D eyes that the mapping is being controlled by a bone, for this I'm using a driver

The problem is, the driver works but only on render view and not on material view

[image]

[image: bad driver :c]

As you can see the eye texture mapping does move on render view, I understand that this is because of the shading type, so if there was a way to make the material shading to work as it does on render mode, that'd be great

there must be some sort of setting or code I am missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated textures don't work in Blender viewport playback](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91347/animated-textures-dont-work-in-blender-viewport-playback)

Comment: umm not what I'm looking for, it's kind of similar but didn't help that much

Comment: This question might be nearly a year old, but I had similar issue and actually found a solution. Check it out to see if it helps you: [Material driver works, but doesn't update on viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129369/material-driver-works-but-doesnt-update-on-viewport/129402#129402)