# Translating Color Data from Cinema4D to Blender

Tags: export, import, color

I have quite a tough (for me, non-Blender user) task on my hands. I need to get color data of an animated object in Cinema 4D into Blender.

My first approach was animating the color of a material in C4D and exporting an FBX, this didn't work.

Next, I tried linking the 'Display Color' of my object to Vertex Colors, and exporting via an Alembic file. This .abc file retains my animated color data if I re-open (and play back) inside C4D, but when I bring the .abc into Blender, it only gets the color from Frame 1, which is no good to me.

Now, I'm trying to potentially rig up a Set Driver / Set Driven expression, taking rotation (X, Y, Z) and mapping them to the R, G, B colors of the material inside Blender. I *think* I have this Set Driver setup, but it doesn't change any colors, I am not sure where things are going wrong. In C4D, using Xpresso, this would be extremely straight forward, but i need the color data to come into Blender, and cannot do so.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, this is a crunch time project.

Comment: "*but it doesn't change any colors*" How are you verifying this, viewport preview? Have in mind that [Blender viewport doesn't preview material animations well](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91347/animated-textures-dont-work-in-blender-viewport-playback/91348#91348), you have to render to see the results

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about viewport playback. I wasn't aware of that, I dont use blender much at all, I'll check into this.