# How to add and play video in the 3d viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, video

Hi so I'm familiar with how to add images to the 3d viewport as planes. But can anyone explain how you would input a video into the 3d viewport such that you can play it in realtime?

My intent would be to create an image as a plane, add the video ontop of a section of this plane. And enable the movie to actually play (change frames and display them in the viewport) as I play from the timeline, and then use the camera to do like a 3d zooom in and down and across the plane that contains the video and back out kind of a thing. But I don't know how to make the video part work for this. I can only do it for static images atm.

[image]

Comment: cycles or internal?

Comment: Would like to know both, but cycles probably most important if I had to choose.

Comment: Cycles samples will be a problem so you'll have to reduce all bounces and use an emit material for the video texture.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91347/animated-textures-dont-work-in-blender-viewport-playback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Internal

1. Add the object.
2. Add a material.
3. Set the material to shadeless
4. Go to the texture tab and add a texture.
5. Load the movie as your texture.
6. Upon loading it enable *Auto Refresh* and press *Match Movie Length* once. The length should be updated.
7. In the 3D viewport, switch to textured or material shading mode.
8. In the shading options (Properties Panel <kbd>N</kbd>), select **GLSL**.

[image: video texture]

---

In the file you linked, the movie is playing, but you have set mapping to UV without specifying a UV Map (the object is not unwrapped). This part doesn't have anything to do with playing a movie, but with UV mapping.

Set the mapping to another type or create a UV map.

[image: mapping coordinates]

Comment: Hi I was applying this to the default 2x2x2 cube on default startup. This is only working if I use the original material already loaded with the cube. If I deleted that material and made a new one with what look to be the same settings....it won't display when I do all the steps. Any ideas wut is going on?

Comment: ya this is only working when I use the default cube. When I add in new cubes it doesn't work, because i have to make a new material other than the default material.

Comment: If I insert a new object and apply the default material it works on the new object, and since I set the texture to that material it loads up the video automatically on the second object. For some reason there's something about the default material that is making it work. So if I deleted all my materials and objects and started with a new material the steps would NOT work for a new material.

Comment: @kite I couldn't recreate your problem. I suggest you create a file from scratch where the textures don't playback and upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then post the link here in the comments and I will take a look.

Comment: Steps done: 1. start with default setting .blend file. Apply steps you stated above to the existing 2x2x2 cube. 2. Upon completion, achieved the desired result. 3. duplicated the cube, went into it's material. added a new material. 4. repeated steps as you stated for this new material, result is as seen in the image above....it shows colours that change but its like a super zoomed section of the video or something weird

Comment: @kite Check out the edit to the answer.

Comment: ahhhh u figured it out the same time i did....i JUST figured it out as well lol and was about to delete all this. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry but how do you do that step in the gif: uv mapping -> unwrap? I'm googling like crazy here but can't find it.

Comment: Nvm i'm good...*Edit mode...'u'. got it. sry., thxs